# Assigning multiple variable values to a single id in jsp?

Tags: java, jsp-tags

I need to assign multiple values to a single id/class.
My jsp code looks like this.

```
<td id='dateHighlight-4-8' onClick="promotion(this);>
<div class="highlight_sm_div" id="highlight_sm-4-8">
<c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="3">
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${i eq 1}">
        <input type="hidden" class="shippingPromoColor" value="pink">
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="${i eq 2}">
        <input type="hidden" class="shippingPromoColor" value="green">
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="${i eq 3}">
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${testValue eq freeDeliveryCharge}">
                <input type="hidden" class="shippingPromoColor" value="red">
            </c:when>
            <c:otherwise>
                <input type="hidden" class="shippingPromoColor" value="blue">
            </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <input type="hidden" class="shippingPromoColor" value="null">                                                                             
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
</c:forEach>
</div>
</td>
```

My script function will be like,,

```
<script>
function promotion(e){
    alert($('.shippingPromoColor').val());
};
</script>
```

shippingPromoColor only returns the value as pink, i have also tried replacing class with id (id="shippingPromoColor") in the input tag. What was i missing here?

Comment: How can a variable have two values?  That's not possible.  Do you mean that you want to be able to change the value on the variable?  If so under what circumstances do you want it to change.

Comment: Your question is very unclear and your code isn't really explaining the problem, can you elaborate on what exactly it is you're trying to do here.

Comment: onClick="promotion(this);>                           In these Statement u missed one more double quote...make this correction